# ExecuteNonQuery doesn't update my table while I am using bind variables

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I am using this code in c# to update my table:

```
public static int updateMytable(string accessCode, string response)
    {

        OracleConnection conn = DB.GetConnection();
        conn.Open();
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "update mytable set response_id= :p_response , response_date=sysdate  where access_code = :p_access_code";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("p_access_code", accessCode);

        cmd.Parameters.Add("p_response", response);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        int res = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
        conn.Close();
        return res;

    }
```

access_code is varchar2

When I remove the condition "where" It updates everything. 
When I use a string command instead of bind variables it works fine too.

```
string str = "update mytable set response_id= "+response+" , response_date=sysdate  where access_code = "+accessCode;
```

Could you advise?

Comment: You need to add the parameters in the command in the same order as they are used in the SQL statement.

Comment: Thank you so much, yes when I put them in the same order , it is working fine :)

Comment: Put `cmd.BindByName = true;` and you can use parameters in any order

Answer (score 1):

Add `cmd.BindByName = true;` in order to bind variables (`:p_response`, `:p_access_code`) by their *names*, not *positions*:

```
public static int updateMytable(string accessCode, string response) {
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessCode))
    return 0; 

  using (OracleConnection conn = DB.GetConnection()) {
    conn.Open();

    using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand()) {
      // When binding varaibles, use their names, not positions
      cmd.BindByName = true;
      cmd.Connection = conn;

      cmd.CommandText = 
        @"update mytable 
             set response_id   = :p_response, 
                 response_date =  sysdate  
           where access_code   = :p_access_code"; 

      cmd.Parameters.Add(":p_response", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
      cmd.Parameters.Add(":p_access_code", OracleDbType.Varchar2);   

      cmd.Parameters[":p_response"].Value = string.IsNullOrEmpty(response) 
        ? (object) (DBNull.Value) 
        : response;

      cmd.Parameters[":p_access_code"].Value = accessCode;  

      return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked fine when i put the params in order
cmd.Parameters.Add("p_response", response);
 cmd.Parameters.Add("p_access_code", accessCode);